# Timer Program Freezes

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am working on a JFrame timer and every time I press start the program freezes
 here is my code :

```
public void startTime() throws InterruptedException{
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        for(int i = 0;i<10000;i++){
            seconds++;
            timeLabel.setText(hours+" : "+ minutes +" : "+seconds);
            switch(seconds){
            case 60:
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
                break;
            }
            switch(minutes){
            case 60 : 
                minutes = 0;
                seconds = 0;
                hours++;
                break;
            }
            thread.sleep(700L);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            startTime();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to make it so that when I press the button it starts the timer
any Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Your `Thread` serves absolutely no purpose. Please read a tutorial on how to use threads.

Comment: The sleep() method in the Thread class is static so it will cause the current UI thread to sleep. You should look into the Timer class.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20354782/2587435) for implementing a label timer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling  Thread.sleep on the Swing event thread.

This:

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
```

does absolutely nothing.

- Consider putting a Runnable in there and doing your off EDT work in that Runnable.
- Or even better use a Swing Timer.

Comment: I think OP has a deep misunderstanding of how `Thread`s and `static` methods work.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks it fixed it but Its going way to fast thats Why I had the thread.sleep in there to make it go slower it worked when I didnt have it in the action listener also its not setting the text every time it goes through the loop

Comment: @user3097544 here's a [Swing Timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Use the Timer's delay to get your desired result